# get absolute path from one absolute and one relative

Tags: python, path

I want to get absolute path from absolute path and relative:

```
absolute1 = '/a/b/c/d.js'
relative = '../../e.js'
absolute2 = getAbsoluteFromAbsoluteAndRelative(absolute1, relative)
```

In this example `absolute2` should be equal `'a/e.js'`

How to write `getAbsoluteFromAbsoluteAndRelative` method?

**Update:**
I found `os.path.abspath` but it takes only one argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your absolute path still contains a filename, so remove that with [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to obtain *just* the directory.

Then join the two and apply [`os.path.normpath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to the result:

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute1), relative))
```

`normpath` normalizes a path with relative references in it; `A/foo/../B` becomes `A/B`, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> absolute1 = '/a/b/c/d.js'
>>> relative = '../../e.js'
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute1), relative))
'/a/e.js'
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I don't know python so had to look up the function names. Good answer.

Comment: allmost ok: `>>> absolute1 = '/a/b/c/d.js'
>>> relative = '../../e.js'
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(absolute1, relative))
'/a/b/e.js'`. But 'a/e.js' expected

Comment: @efr: already adjusted; I missed the fact that your absolute path had a filename in it still.

Answer (score 0):

Try `absolute2 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute1), relative)`

Edit: Martijn beat me to it. Wrapping this in `os.path.normpath` is the way to go.